# Change the directory of a file to be saved

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that I deployed as a library. Inside my shiny app, I write a json file in real time, I want to write this file in the working directory of each user. Nevertheless, the file is written in the directory of the library.(Please refer the code below)

**app.R**

```
library(Tree)
ui <- htmlTemplate("www/Tree.html",
        text_output = tableOutput("table2")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session){

    # This block fires each time we receive a message from JavaScript
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
        #Write json file
        json_value = input$jsonData
        write(json_value, paste0(getwd(),"/",fileName, ".json"))

    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui , server)
```

I though that with the function `getwd()`I will be able to see my json file in my working directory but taht is not happening. My json file is written in the directory of the library

This directory

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Tree/
```

How can I change my code to be able to see my jsonfile in the RProject which the user wants to work?

Comment: Avoid messing up by writing up files on your users desktop. Using a [Download button](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/downloadButton.html) instead offers your users to save the file wherever they want

Comment: Thank you! But save the file in the project working directory is what I need, without buttons

Comment: You can have a look at [rprojroot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rprojroot/index.html)

Comment: How exactly are your users running this shiny app inside your package? It's unclear to me what would be changing the working directory.

Comment: library(Tree)
createTree("HelloWorld") This function deploy the shiny app and returns the path where the file "HelloWorld" is written. I want that the file HelloWorld stay in the working directory of my user, instead of this path /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Tree/HelloWorld.json

Comment: Could you please specify what directory exactly you want the files to be saved in? The package directory obviously **is** the working directory. Which one do you need, exactly?

Comment: The directory where the user loads the library(Tree). F example. If the user creates a project in the path (~/Documents/RProject) and the user loads the library(Tree) then I want my json file in (~/Documents/RProject/myFile.json)

Answer (score 0):

A shiny app is running in your browser and, as a concequence, subject to strict safety regulations imposed by the browser. There are plenty of restrictions regarding the file system to make sure that web pages cannot freely roam your hard drive. That is why there might not be a solution with a good user experience to achieve what you want.

1. The safest solution would be the download button (as suggested by @HubertL).
2. If you want to work with the users' home directory you can get the path with `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"))` (at least on Windows it works). Now you can work with that path. Use `OutputPath <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), fileName)` to create the path *%HOME%/fileName*.
3. The third alternative (I can think of) is a simple `textInput`. Users can paste a string there that represents the path to the directory where they want the file to be stored. Check the string with `dir.exists` and use it if it is valid.

Comment: But what alternative I have? if I don't want buttons in my app, What happens if the user creates a project in his Documents directory and then he/she called the app. I want to have this flexibility to be able to see my json file in the current working directory.